# How to store a pointer variable to Form1 in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to save a pointer to Form1 in my Painter class. My attempt here:

```
class Painter {
    private Form _form;
    public void setFormPtr( Form form ) { 
        _form = form; 
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Painter painter;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        painter.setFormPtr( this );
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work (it says NullPointerException near this). What's wrong with this code? I really need a pointer to Form1 in my Painter class. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a painter with `painter = new Painter()` first.

But I would add a constructor to the `Painter` class accepting a form as parameter

```
public class Painter
{
    private readonly Form _form;

    public Painter(Form form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }
}
```

and then create the painter in the `Form1` constructor like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    painter = new Painter(this);
}
```

This ensures that the form is assigned in the painter. There is no `setFormPtr` method that you can forget to call.